# Easy way to extract several nodes together in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

The XML is like this (only one `DateCreated` node in a document):

```
 <DateCreated>
  <Year>2011</Year>
  <Month>07</Month>
  <Day>11</Day>
 </DateCreated>
```

The result I need is like this:

```
2011-07-11
```

I think I need at least three selectors `DateCreated Year`, `DateCreated Month` and `DateCreated Day`, which looks quite clumsy.. I was just wondering that if there's a one-liner or easier way to do task like this. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: try ajax method in jquery, here's the API documentation

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: It depends on whether the order is always the same; it doesn't necessarily have to be, because a different order doesn't affect the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
[].join.call(
  $.map($('DateCreated').children(), function(){ 
    return $(this).text();
  }).toArray(),
  '-'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this satisfies.

```
var xml = "<DateCreated>  <Year>2011</Year>  <Month>07</Month>  <Day>11</Day> </DateCreated>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
output = $xml.find("Year").text() + '-' + 
         $xml.find("Month").text() + '-' + 
         $xml.find("Day").text();
console.log(output);
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$xml.children().map(function(){ return $(this).text() }).get().join('-')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aZgDR/)